# What do i need to use to make a website like etherscan?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, truffle, ganache

I want to make a website like etherscan which can search for smart contracts or balance of ETH wallet.

Now I am using truffle, ganache, web3.js, React, metamask to practice ethreum blockchain,

and got a little bit of concept of it.

My next goal is making the website like etherscan and want to run it properly, not just for fun.

in this case, which library should I use?

It will be connected to real Ethereum mainnet, so should I use GETH ?

so will it be Geth, web3.js, React? (If I choose React for front-end)

Thank you in advance!

I tried with ganache, truffle, web3.js, React, Metamask for practicing but have no idea what to use when it comes to the real mainnet Etheream.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems that you want to build explorer. Maybe this opensource project can help https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet for something like this is to use a service like [Infura](https://infura.io). They make it extremely easy to access Ethereum network data, and they can provide access to archive data. The only drawback is that they are a centralized service - if decentralized access to the data is required for your project, running your own GETH node may be the way to go.